# Can we use Angular 2 as server side script?

Tags: apache, angular, frameworks, server-side

I need to know if we can use Angular 2 as server side scripting.
Is it possible to run it on Apache?
If yes, How we can run it on the server?
I use CPanel hosting

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Angular is a **client side** framework. So no.
Yes you can deploy an angular 2 app on apache. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) for more details